# How add physics to Phaser 3 sprite?

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

I am trying to implement the [Phaser 3 documentation for physics sprites](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite.html) in a typescript project, but this seems less straightforward than expected:

**NOT WORKING**

```
export class BMO extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {

    constructor(scene) {
        super(scene, 100,150, "bmo")
        this.scene.add.existing(this)
    }

    create(){
        this.setVelocity(100, 200);
        this.setBounce(1, 1);
        this.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
    }
}
```

But when creating a `new BMO()` the sprite has no physics. 
The physics engine itself is working because I can pass an image and it works:

**WORKING**

```
export class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {

  create(){
    let logo = this.physics.add.image(400, 100, 'bmosmall')
    logo.setVelocity(100, 200);
    logo.setBounce(1, 1);
    logo.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
  }
}
```

**FIX?**

So perhaps the sprite still needs to be added to the physics engine manually (even though it's a physics sprite), but it's not possible to pass the whole sprite as an argument:

```
 export class BMO extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {
     create(){
        this.scene.physics.add.sprite(this)
     }
 }
```

How do I create a Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to add `scene.physics.add.existing(this);` to your class

```
export class BMO extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite {

    constructor(scene) {
        super(scene, 100,150, "bmo")
        scene.physics.add.existing(this); // add this line
        this.scene.add.existing(this)
    }

    create(){
        this.setVelocity(100, 200);
        this.setBounce(1, 1);
        this.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should include a physics section into Phaser.Game config.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same question.  I found the answer here:

https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/arcade-body/

In short:

```
scene.physics.add.existing(gameObject, isStatic)
```

I haven't checked yet which types of GameObjects can be added or extended this way but I'm guessing any of them can, and not just `Physics.*.*`.